# count object Parse Swift + tableView Section

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I'm quiet new to Parse so i'm sticking with the developper Guide and Basic Functions.
Unfortunately it seems that there is at least one error on the documentation regarding the countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock function.
Here is my function

```
var categoryCount: [Int] = []
```

func getNumberOfItemInCategory() {

```
    for category in categories {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Amiibos")
        query.whereKey("category", equalTo: category)
        query.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (count, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                var result = Int(count)
                println("there is \(result) in \(category)")
 //               println( "TypeName0 = \(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(result))")
                self.categoryCount.append(result)
            }
        }

    }
    for toto in categoryCount {
        println("toto: \(toto)")
    }
    println("categoryCountFunc: \(self.categoryCount)")


}
```

This function doesn't return an Int but a Int32. I tried to change the return value with `return Int(count)` but i get an error.

Then i would like to use this function in the function:

```
let categories = ["name1", "name2"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if categoryCount.isEmpty {
        return 0
    }
    else {
        return categoryCount[section]
    }
    }
```

Any help would be very appreciated thank you very much

[edit - add]
I added a function to get the result and refresh the table.

```
func makeRequest() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.getMyObjectsFromParse()
        self.getNumberOfItemInCategory()
        self.tableView.reloadData()           
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` returns `void`, and takes a block parameter which also returns `void`.

At the heart of the problem with the posted code is the idea of asynchronously computing a count on the datasource method that requires an immediate result.

The better design is to just fetch the data for each section up front, place the result in the datasource array, and reload the table.  Then `numberOfRowsInSection` can do what it was meant to do and just return the count of an array.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!
I was able to create a  var in add the result in it. Well sort of. No idea why, when i println the result it display without issue and as an Integer. But when i try to .append to my variable array it doesnt seem to work.
I edited my first post